# Angular 17: Module "url" has been externalized for browser compatibility

Tags: httpclient, server-side-rendering, angular17

After adding a route to a component that injected to it a service with httpClient i get this browser console errors:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoBP1.png)

there are two main errors:

```
express.js?v=2bced265:1288 Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.ReadStream" in client code. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.
```

AND

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Mime.define (express.js?v=2bced265:21027:11)
    at node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js (express.js?v=2bced265:21056:10)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=665f2b59:41:50)
    at node_modules/send/index.js (express.js?v=2bced265:21291:16)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=665f2b59:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (express.js?v=2bced265:22672:16)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=665f2b59:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (express.js?v=2bced265:22816:23)
    at __require2 (chunk-X6JV76XL.js?v=665f2b59:41:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js?v=2bced265:24764:17)
```

I searched all over the internet and i am not able to get a solution for this error, also I am not if the problem comes from the route or the server side rendering I am really stuck and don't know how to fix it.